# Facing Problem with admin-ajax.php URL - Getting 404 with AJAX call

Tags: plugins, ajax

I am trying to get an ajax response on WordPress, currently, it's showing me a 404 error on the staging server but on dev it's working fine.

I know the problem is due to the use of "forward-slash(/)" in the URL on staging but on dev it's working with or without forward-slash just after admin-ajax.php.
Please check the below URL so that you all can understand this in detail

**Staging Environment:**

URL NOT WORKING(with / ) on staging:

```
staging/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php/category/movies/?action=get_movies?action=get_my_post
```

URL WORKING WITHOUT ( / ) on staging:

```
staging/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php/category/movies/?action=get_my_post
```

**Dev Environment:**

URL WORKING(with / ) on staging:

```
staging/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php/category/movies//?action=get_my_post
```

URL WORKING WITHOUT ( / ) on staging:

```
staging/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php/category/movies/?action=get_my_post
```

as you can see if I remove forward-slash after admin-ajax.php it's working fine on staging but with a forward-slash , it's not working, where is dev environment it's working with our without forward-slash

Ajax code:

```
function get_movies()
{
   require_once themespro_classifier_addon_template_exsits('movies/templates/grid');
    get_search_tems( $category_for_push ,$paged);
  
    wp_die();  
    
}
```

Comment: `.php` files generally wouldn't have a trailing forward slash `/`. Have you checked your HTACCESS file rules in the WordPress root folder?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee yes I have checked we are using the same .htaccess on both servers

Comment: How are you making the request? Are you using a relative URL?

Comment: @JacobPeattie yes i am using relative url

Comment: You should try an absolute URL.

Comment: I tried that too it's not working, do i need to add something in htacess or should i do some changes in the apache server.
As you can see everything is working fine in dev @JacobPeattie

Comment: What is producing the URLs with the forward slash in them? `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )`? Or is it just something that your JavaScript is adding?

Comment: @bosco I am adding that, like am also passing few more details that I haven't mentioned.
Down is the real url
staging/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php/category/movies?action=get_movies

Comment: The only thing after `admin-ajax.php` should be URL query parameters, `admin-ajax.php/category` etc is _extremely_ unusual. Have you considered using the REST API instead? You **must** use an absolute URL with `admin-ajax.php`, but with the REST API you will get a pretty URL to make requests to, and it will tell you in human readable language what went wrong if it fails, it's much easier

Comment: @TomJNowell no we are not planning to go with REST API

Comment: Why are you not planning to use the REST API? I've noticed your question does not include code, can you edit it to include code. The old admin ajax API does not require `.htaccess` changes to operate

Comment: @TomJNowell we are using a plugin template to show all movies, well I have added the code in question. Can you tell me why it's working on dev I believe that we can solve this if we change some settings in apache? As .htaccess on both server are same so i believe by changing apache settings we achieve this

Comment: having the slash on the end should not work on either, and is not how admin-ajax.php is supposed to work. That it works at all on dev is the bug. I've read the code you added to your question but I do not see any javascript, or AJAX handlers, or code that makes AJAX calls, there is a lot of missing code. None of what I can see in your question matches how the `admin-ajax.php` API is supposed to work